# Firebase push notification not delivered if device is idle for few minutes and no charging state

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Firebase push notification is working fine for all three states of app: foreground, background, killed.

But notification not delivered if device is idle for few minutes and no charging state.
However on charging push notification is working no matter how long idle time is.

I have tried with:

1. disabling 'Power saving mode'.
2. disabling 'Adaptive power saving mode'.
3. battery optimization for app.
4. added in manifest

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   ```
5. removed [android:exported="false"] from

   ```
   <service
        android:name="firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" =>[android:exported="false"]>
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
   ```
6. 

```
{
    "registration_ids": [
        "ei0....ySI"
    ],
    "data": {
       "priority" : "high",
        "title": "msg title",
        "body": "msg body"
    },
    "android": {
        "priority": "high"
    },
    "apns": {
        "headers": {
            "apns-priority": "10"
        }
    },
    "webpush": {
        "headers": {
            "Urgency": "high"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: push notifs don't guarantee instant delivery

Comment: As its description says, the `python-idle` tag is for the IDLE IDE for the Python language.

Answer (score 2):

Moving **"priority": "high"** to the root worked.
Now payload is like:

```
{
    "registration_ids": ["cWy......FrN"],
    "data": {
        "title": "this is msg title",
        "body": "this is msg body"
    },
    "priority": "high"
}
```